# Is there a way to persist a login across MSM sites?

Tags: members, multi-site-manager, login, single-sign-on

I'm exploring MSM for a new site and need to provide a single login for members and allow them to jump from site1 to site 2 with a single session. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you setup well following variable in the index file of the both sites:

```
$assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'default_site';
$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://domain.com/admin.php';
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://domain.com';
```

You need to add a variable in config file also:

```
$config['allow_multi_logins'] = "y";
```

The member will be logged in for both sites and can be able to switch from site1 to site2 as logged in.

Hope, it would help you.

Comment: I'll double check but I'm pretty sure I added those settings. I should add that I am bootstrapping with the FocusLab config.

Comment: I would suggest you to recheck the config setting for allow_multi_logins which is being checked during member login process.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. For my setup the necessary config was

```
$config['multi_login_sites'] = "http://somesite.com/|http://anothersite.com/";
```

where you provide a pipe delimited list of each of your site's URLs. You will have to make sure that the URLs you provide are an exact match for what ExpressionEngine has for the `{site_url}`.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now. It works with the member login form on my front end templates. However, it does not work the admin (cp) login. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected behavior is. In my case I was only concerned about multi-login on the front end since my Admins do all their work from the default site CP. But in a quick test, logging in to the default site CP also logs me into the site 2 CP.